# Change the color of UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Do anyone know how to change the color of `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton`, the new button added with iOS 7?

Comment: No, [there's no information whatsoever available about that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=uitableviewcellaccessorydetailbutton). Apple [certainly wouldn't update their documentation for such a thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the tintColor of the cell. For example:

```
[cell setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```